# Writing a data.frame into a spreadsheet: Encoding problems

Tags: r, character-encoding, instagram, xlconnect

I have extraced some data from Instagram. All of the API request are done by

```
fromJSON(rawToChar(GET(url)$content))
```

When I try to display that dataframe within a Shiny application using `renderTable()`
I get the error message

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 
  invalid input 'Ivy Manhattan í ¼í½‰' in 'utf8towcs'
```

Ok, it looks like an encoding problem. `Ivy Manhattan í ¼í½‰` is the full name of a Instagram user. Intersting is, that the output is being rendered properly when I use `rederDataTable()`. Sure, why dont I just use it then?

The actual problem is, that I want to be able to write this dataframe to a spreadsheet using the package `XLConnect`. And when the program reaches the command `writeWorksheet(wb, data)` I get the same error.

Is it because those characters are unknown to R? How can I "filter" the dataframe for problematic strings?

First Edit as reaction to MrFlick's comment:

Well what I get when I fetch a request to the API is

```
GET(paste("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/143/?client_id=f714dd*********58b18f"))$content

[1] 7b 22 6d 65 74 61 22 3a 7b 22 63 6f 64 65 22 3a 32 30 30 7d 2c 22 64 61 74 61 22  3a 7b 22 75 73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65 22 ... AND SO ON
```

`rawToChar()` converts that to the JSON string which is readable/accepted by `fromJSON()`

@MrFlick Second edit:

Here is the output of Sys.getlocale() from my machine:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252
LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252"
```

GET declares the fetched string as encoded with utf-8. When I try to convert those with

```
iconv(x, from="utf-8", to="ASCII",sub="")
```

Nothing changes.

Comment: Do you know what the encoding used by the API is? The rawToChar seems suspicious. Are you on Windows? In stead of `$content` you should probably use `content()` with an `encoding=` parameter. Most likely it's UTF-8.

Comment: Try converting to character-mode first. They are probably factor columns if you used the default input methods.

Comment: Where exaclty should I convert it? before/after `fromJSON`? And how I do it? Just by using `as.character`?

Comment: Thos instagrammers always use all kind of weird characters i ntheir usernames/full names. That might be the problem rather than factor columns, dont you think? :/

Comment: What does `content(GET(url), as="parsed", encoding="UTF-8")` do? You really want to make sure you get the encoding correct. It's important.

Comment: I understand that. I extracted all the basic info about users. There is no problem with those except for the full name. Could it be encoded differently than the rest of the JSON string? So far Im just happy about my workaround. But tomorrow I'll try your idea as well. It would be defiently safer than my "fix" ;) Thanks!

Comment: Well I couldnt resist and tried it already (jeez its half past 3 a.m. alread -.- )... But your way works as well! Somehow even better since some weird chars jsut disappeared. So, thanks again! Keep looking at my questions please, ur very helpful :)

Comment: Oh and If you just post it as an answer, I'll mark it!

Comment: Hm I oversaw something. The problem are the unicode characters inside the names. When I use your method with `encoding="UTF-8"` I recieve sometimes things like "<U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800><U+2800>JENNY". Those are clearly unicode characters. How to manage those?

Comment: Hm I guess I should just crop the strings by looking for this "<xxx>" pattern. Than I got rid of those...

Comment: We don't get automatically notified when you a post new comment or edit your post. If you make an edit, add a comment and use "@" with a username to notify that person you have updated your question.

Comment: Edited the question again @MrFlick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to just encode the JSON part `data$fullname` since that seems to be the problem. I tried `Encoding(data$fullname) = "UTF-8"` at first which didnt resolve the situation. But then I switched to `latin1`and the spreadsheet happend to be written. Thanks for your pushy ideas! :)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed above, it would probably be better to use

```
content(GET(url), as="parsed", encoding="UTF-8")
```

this takes advantage of the `httr` package's ability to decode the content for you.

Note that when you see `<U+2800>` in output, that does not mean that those exact characters appear in the string. That's R's way of escaping unicode characters just like it adds extra slashed to escape other special characters like `\r`. You are seeing those characters because if your locale settings. You didn't mention what OS you are on. The Mac will use UTF-8 by default and should try to display those characters. I don't have access to a windows machine to test what the default is there. They seem to appear as "" when the locale "LC_ALL" is set to "C". This returns

```
Sys.getlocale()
# [1] "C/C/C/C/C/en_US.UTF-8"

x <- "\u2800\u2800\u2800Jenny";
print(x)
# [1] "<U+2800><U+2800><U+2800>Jenny"
```

so there aren't actually less-than/greater-than symbols or capital U's in the string. That's just how the C encoding will display them. If you want to remove non-ascii characters, you could do

```
iconv(x, from="UTF-8", to="ASCII", sub="")
# [1] "Jenny"
```

Excel may very well be able to handle other types of encoding but I personally don't know how that's managed with `XLConnect`

Comment: Sorry I thought I mentioned that I am using a windows machine. The solution we are looking for here is supposed to work on both Mac and Windows computers.

Comment: This should work just fine on both Windows and Mac. The only thing different might be how it's displayed in the console/GUI. When you did `iconv` what was your `x` object? At this point you really need to create a reproducible example so we can run the exact same code otherwise further help may not be possible because we can't see the exact data you are working with to know what's going on.